# Reliability of this site

Tags: discussion

So this is an important question I have to ask. So how reliable is stack overflow, like the entire community? Is it reliable source of info or are there any misleading info anywhere just like in some other sites like say Quora. How reliable or unreliable is this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally reliable, because the community can upvote good answers and downvote bad ones. It's still possible to find incorrect information here, but I've overall found it a reliable source.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I agree with this. Some care should be taken with posts that have attracted either very little or very much attention. In the first case, not many votes have been cast and unreliable content may persist. In the second case, questions may have appeared in the "hot network questions" on sister sites and attracted votes from laymen, which are less reliable as quality indicators.